# Entity Framework Orderby One to Many Entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've seen similar to this but cant find an answer. I have 2 enities Publication and Author. 
Author is NOT mandatory and when I OrderBy Publication.Author.Surname I get NullReferenceException because a Publication dosnt always have a related Author. How do I write this simple query and why the heck dosnt EhtityFramework know how to deal with this?

```
public class Publication {
[Key]
public int ID { get; set; }

public string Title { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Author")]
public int? AuthorId { get; set; }
public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class Author{
[Key]
public virtual int ID { get; set; }

public virtual string Forename { get; set; }

public virtual string Surname { get; set; }
}

this.db.Publications
    .OrderBy(p=>p.Author.Surname)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(model.PageSize).ToList();
```

Fails because a Publication dosnt always have a related Author. Note: db is the Entity Framework DBContext as below:

```
public class PPRDBContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the type of db.Publications? If it is an IQueryable (e.g. IDbSet) EF will translate the expression to SQL code, that is, p.Author.Surname isn't actually executed, so it won't throw an exception. EF will generate something like an outer join and NULL authors will be ordered as other values. I got this working without further modifications..

Comment: If you're getting the exception it can be a sign that it's an IEnumerable instead of IQueryable, which would mean that the sequence is in-memory.

Comment: lgoncalves - I added the db (DBContext) code to show where I get Publications. So Publications is a DbSet but it still throws the exception.

Comment: I have it working here.. Can't understand why that's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not EF's fault - it's a common trap with any language I know of when accessing properties of referenced objects.

Depending on whether you want NULL values  to come first you could do something like:

```
.OrderBy(p=> p.Author == null ? "" : p.Author.Surname)
```

If you want the NULL values to come last use something like:

```
.OrderBy(p=> p.Author == null ? "ZZZZZ" : p.Author.Surname)
```

Comment: Yeah I dont like the answer either (sorry D Stanley) - but it works. I'd rather EF sorted this out. I'm fairly new to EF so it might be something I'm doing.